# If one of the multiple queries running one after another fails in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing an API,
In this API I have two Models: `SongModel` and `UserModel`.
When I save a new song, I also run another query to add the song._id to the user who created it.
But due to my mistake in code, the second query threw an error and there was a problem,
the song that was just created had no means to be updated and deleted in the future
because the user had no way of identifying that song without its _id.

For now, I have fixed my code, but in the future, so that my site would not face a similar issue again,
How can I handle it?

I searched different articles and questions but couldn't find any practices to counter this.
Is there any method in mongoose or any package to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [MongoDB Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/). With it, either everything will succeed, or nothing will.

Basically, you first have to create a `session`, and use that `session` for all you queries. After all the queries, you will commit the transaction.

To use transactions with Mongoose, you can check [their official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html).

Here is the how the code can look like:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const addNewSong = async (req, res) => {
  const { song } = req.body;
  const user_id = req.user._id;

  // Start a session
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();

  try {
    // Start a transaction
    session.startTransaction();

    // Create new song
    const song = await Songs.create([song], { session });

    // Update user
    await Users.updateOne({ _id: user_id }, { $addToSet: { songs: song[0]._id } }, { session });

    // Commit the transaction
    await session.commitTransaction();

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  } finally {
    // End session
    session.endSession();
  }
};
```